# SQL Display details and count fields through checks

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created an Oracle database which contains information regarding renting flats/apartments. I am trying to create a SQL script which will, first, count how many students have not paid their first invoice (so there should be an "is not null" check on this field) and, second, display their details.

Here is an example of the data the table is called INVOICE:

```
+-----------+-------+---------------+---------------+----------------+--------+---------------+-------------+
| INVOICEID | PRICE | PAYMENTMETHOD | FIRSTREMINDER | SECONDREMINDER | RENTID | PAYMENTSTATUS |  DATESENT   |
+-----------+-------+---------------+---------------+----------------+--------+---------------+-------------+
|         1 |   415 | Visa          | 10/FEB/2016   | -              |      1 | Paid          | 15/MAR/2016 |
|         2 |   600 | Cash          | 15/FEB/2016   | -              |      2 | Unpaid        | 12/MAR/2016 |
|         3 |   750 | Visa          | 10/FEB/2016   | 15/MAR/2016    |      1 | Paid          | 15/MAR/2016 |
+-----------+-------+---------------+---------------+----------------+--------+---------------+-------------+
```

Using this data, the SQL statement should return the details for number 2 in the table and count them.

I'd be grateful if anyone could help with this because I have no clue where to start. SQL is not my main programming language.

Comment: Any reason you want a PL/SQL procedure and not a straight SQL query? The mantra among Oracle pros is "don't do in PL/SQL what you can do in SQL". There are good reasons for that, to do with performance, but you may have your reasons.

Comment: You mention "how many students" but there is no specific student data in your sample. Does your table, in fact, also have a student_id or tenant_id column, or something like that? Otherwise how do you want to count how many students? Do you assume each invoice is for a different student?

Comment: I have edited the post now, I would actually prefer it to be a straight SQL statement if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The query below enumerates the invoice #'s per `RENTID` and allows you to select 1st invoices that were unpaid:

```
select * from (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by rentid order by invoiceid) invoice_number
    from mytable
) t where invoice_number = 1 and paymentstatus = 'Unpaid'
```

If you just want the count, then replace `select *` with `select count(*)`

```
select count(*) from (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by rentid order by invoiceid) invoice_number
    from mytable
) t where invoice_number = 1 and paymentstatus = 'Unpaid'
```

Another way that checks whether `secondreminder is null` to determine whether an invoice is a 1st invoice

```
select count(*)
from mytable
where secondreminder is null 
and paymentstatus = 'Unpaid'
```

Comment: @DaveDavidson why not?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this should suffice...

To get the count:

```
select count(*) from invoice where paymentstatus = 'Unpaid'
```

To get the details for those rows:

```
select * from invoice where paymentstatus = 'Unpaid'
```

You mentioned something about an "is not null" check "on this field" - what field are you referring to? Isn't the paymentstatus column sufficient?